# How to display jpeg images from Postgres in Qlik Sense dashboard

Tags: postgresql, qliksense, bytea

It's my first dashboard in Qlik Sense and I'm trying to show the last 5 images stored in one of my postgres tables. Images are jpeg, base64 encoded and stored as 'bytea' type in Postgres. I have a view in Postgres ('photo__last_5' ) that returns the last 5 images. In my load script in Qlik, I have defined the following:

```
[last_5]:
Load
created,
'data:image/jpg;base64,' & base64_bytes;
SELECT created, base64_bytes
FROM photo__last_5;
```

In order to include these photos on my sheet (and after having read this document [here](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-read-images-from-a-database-and-display-in-Qlik-Sense-and/ta-p/1711247)), I've added a Map object on my sheet, set the base map to None, turned off the other settings so the object appears blank (having done that, I don't see my object as blank/transparent as they show in the document but rather as "white", don't know if it's normal or not). After that I've added three layers (point (0,0), point (25,25) and my background image) with outline color of white and opacity set to 0 for point layers. After that I've created a Table object that lists the 5 photos, so I can select one. Having done that I was expecting my image would be displayed on the map object but nothing appears.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by loading the image *string* (encoded in base64) and not the base64 *bytes*.